# Linking glfw and assimp for a "standalone" project

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

I have a [project](https://github.com/KingOfLuL/OpenGL.git) following [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/). It works fine on my pc, but not on others since the libraries are not installed there. I have assimp, glfw, glm and stb installed through msys, so they are not directly included in the project. How would i need to link the libraries so that the application runs on other mashines? Ideally i would like to use static links (not sure how tho), but including the libraries with the appilcation would be fine too.

Makefile:

```
CC = g++

SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/**/*.cpp) $(wildcard lib/**/**/*.c)

LIBS = -lassimp.dll -lglfw3.dll

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g3 -O2 -Ilib -Ilib/glad/include -Isrc

OUT = bin/main

all:
    $(CC) $(SRC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(OUT)
```

Comment: If the recipients of your application don't have the DLL's needed then they need to install them. Or you should link *statically*, instead of to the DLL's.

Comment: Additionally you can put them in the same folder as your solution (or sub folder) and link them using the $(SolutionDir) macro, so that any computer will be able to find them.

Comment: If I want to link to libglfw3.a and libassimp.a for static linking I get a bunch of undefined reference errors (unz.. and inflate.. for assimp and __imp_.. for glfw). In the Makefile I changed "-lassimp.dll -lglfw3.dll" to "-l:libglfw3.a -l:libassimp.a". (I am not using Visual Studio but Visual Studio Code)
If I put the lib<>.dll.a files in the project glfw3.dll and assimp.dll cant be found and I dont know how to link to those.

Comment: Static libraries are not stand-alone like a DLL, you need to link with all dependencies of a static library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static linking is now working!
The commands for linking now look like this:

```
 -l:libglfw3.a -opengl32 -lgdi32 -l:libassimp.a -lminizip -lz
```

I just had some libraries missing that glfw and assimp depended on.